# DB2 Concatenate string to error inside stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I want to add the value of a variable to the error text, but got an error due to syntax.

```
DECLARE VALUE VARCHAR;
--doing some checks

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '99'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Value is not valid: ''' || VALUE || ''';
```

**{0:0} An unexpected token "|| ''" was found following "valid'".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SIGNAL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-signal) statement supports either a string constant or a string variable in the right part of the SET statement as described in the documentation. No expressions are allowed there.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_VALUE VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT 'SOME VALUE';
  DECLARE V_MSG VARCHAR (70);

  SET V_MSG = 'Value is not valid: ''' || V_VALUE || '''';
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75099' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = V_MSG;
END@
```

Comment: 70 is the max size according to the documentation -- makes sense to define V_MSG that size